# Intel XDK Cannot Run with your System Configuration

Tags: intel-xdk

I installed Intel XDK on Windows 10. After installing, it gives me an error. What should I do?

> The Intel XDK cannot run with your system configuration. Your system firewall seems to be blocking localhost traffic. The Intel XDK runs a local server must be able to send http request to that server. We tried sending http request to http://127.0.0.1:58889 but it was blocked. Please adjust your firewall to allow traffic to 127.0.0.1 on port 58889.

Screenshot of the same error:
[image: Img]

Comment: Did you add the exception in Windows firewall?

Comment: How to add exception